# invalid standard action error on Tomcat

Tags: jsp, javabeans, usebean

I have started to learn JSP and I tried to write my first JSP page and use `<jsp:usebean/>` action tag.
The bean is an empty class that has no property and only one method `print()`:

```
package foo;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class FirstBean implements Serializable {
    public String print() {
        return "hello, world";
    }
}
```

I compiled the **FirstBean.java** file into foo directory which resides in the **WEB-INF/classes** directory.
Then I have the **FistBean.jsp** file with the following content:

```
   <html>
        <head>
             <jsp:usebean id="name" class="foo.firstBean"/>
        </head>
         <body>
            <! String st=name.Print();%>
            <p> the string stored in JSP is <%=st%></p>
        </body>
   </html>
```

In the above code I instantiate the firstBean instance via `usebean` action. Then I call its `print()` method which shoud return a String "Hello, world". But when I try to type **localhost:8080/jsp/firstBean.jsp** file Tomcat gives me the following error:

> message /firstBean.jsp(3,7) Invalid standard action
>
> description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.

I get the following exception:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /firstBean.jsp(3,7) Invalid
>   standard action
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:88)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseStandardAction(Parser.java:1131)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1424)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:185)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
>     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)

It will be much appreciated if someone could help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The right [syntax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_syntax.htm)  for JSP code is with percent sign

```
      <% String st=name.Print();%>
```